# Deploy QML application with localstorage plugin

Tags: qt, plugins, deployment, qml

I have deployed a QML application (static build on windows, following this how-to: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW). However, the qml_import_trace (screenshot below) reveals that LocalStorage is loaded from the Qt/Static folder on the development computer, not from the release folder. Hence, when launched at another computer, the LocalStorage module is not found. How may the LocalStorage plugin/module be shipped with the application?

[image]

Including the following lines in the .pro files will give svg support. Am I only missing a qtplugin for sql/localstorage? In that case, what is the proper plugin name? Also, where can I find valid inputs for QTPLUGIN+= and QT+= ?

```
QTPLUGIN += qsvg
QT += svg sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to copy the needed files to the release folder automatically.

Use the `windeployqt.exe` (in `qt/bin` folder) with `--qmldir` option. It will scan the given path for QML files and collect the QML components imported in those files.

Answer (score 0):

A solution, although not optimal, was to manually copy the QtQuick/LocalStorage folder from the static folder into the release folder